# Typescript typings.d.ts failing with parsing error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, typescript-typings

When I run lint my typescript code it throws a parsing error:

```
  2:3  error  Parsing error: Only declares and type imports are allowed inside declare module

  1 | declare module "*.json" {
> 2 |   var value: any;
    |   ^
  3 |   export default value;
  4 | }
```

I am new to TypeScript and am really not sure how to fix this?

My tsconfig is as follows:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "isolatedModules": true,  // Warn you if you write certain code that can’t be correctly interpreted by a single-file transpilation process.
    "outDir": "./dist/",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "ES5",
    "jsx": "react",
    "lib": ["ESNEXT", "DOM", "DOM.Iterable", "ES5"],
    "allowJs": true, // Allow JavaScript files to be imported inside your project, instead of just .ts and .tsx
    "checkJs": true,  // When checkJs is enabled then errors are reported in JavaScript files. This is the equivalent of including // @ts-check at the top of all JavaScript files which are included in your project.
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true, // Allow default imports from modules with no default export
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "types": ["node", "webpack-env", "@wdio/sync", "mocha", "expect-webdriverio"],
    "strict": false // Enables all strict type checking options (This is too restrictive for the current code base)
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/**.ts",
    "test/**/**.ts"
  ]
}
```

Should I exclude it?  This is in a React code base with Webpack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
error  Parsing error: Only declares and type imports are allowed inside declare module
```

> The answer is in the error itself.

The `declare module` is to declare the types, but what you're doing in your code is defining a variable (value not type), so it is just not allowed and doesn't make sense too. Just remove that line the error will go.

If you could tell what you actually trying to achieve, we could help you in that.